# AzureAD Powershell on Mac

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

using Powershell I am trying to retrieve information such as EmployeeID, Manager, Job Title etc, but I am only able to get basic information. Can anyone please help me?

Once I have connected to Azure using the following:

```
connect-azaccount -TenantId 'b4a42f9f-57e8-4535-80d8-2ff03a6240f8'
```

I then type

```
Get-AzADUser -ObjectId 2a6aa9b5-1519-480c-9014-57296457a21c
```

which returns the following:

```
UserPrincipalName : joy.mia@lts.onmicrosoft.com
ObjectType        : User
UsageLocation     : GB
GivenName         : Joyn
Surname           : Miah
AccountEnabled    : True
MailNickname      : joy.mia
Mail              : 
DisplayName       : Joy Mia
Id                : 2a6aa9b5-1519-480c-9014-57296457a21c
Type              : Member
```

Is it possible to retrieve information im looking for? Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

`Get-AzUser` doesn't return more than that, but you can get the information from the CmdLets `Get-AzureADUser` and `Get-AzureADUserManager`, both from the Graph-based `AzureAD` module (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0).

EmployeeId is hidden in "ExtensionProperty" and the Manager needs a separate command. If you want them listed as normal attributes you can use calculated properties like this:

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId 8527a585-7692-4fa8-9db4-ba3c4946a890 |
    Select-Object *,
        @{n='EmployeeId';e={$_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId}},
        @{n='Manager';e={ (Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).DisplayName }}
```

You'll need to connect first using `Connect-AzureAD`.

If you want the UPN of the Manager instead just change "DisplayName" to "UserPrincipalName"

With the command above, you'll get all these (apart from EmployeeId and Manager):

```
ExtensionProperty
DeletionTimestamp
ObjectId
ObjectType
AccountEnabled
AgeGroup
AssignedLicenses
AssignedPlans
City
CompanyName
ConsentProvidedForMinor
Country
CreationType
Department
DirSyncEnabled
DisplayName
FacsimileTelephoneNumber
GivenName
IsCompromised
ImmutableId
JobTitle
LastDirSyncTime
LegalAgeGroupClassification
Mail
MailNickName
Mobile
OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier
OtherMails
PasswordPolicies
PasswordProfile
PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
PostalCode
PreferredLanguage
ProvisionedPlans
ProvisioningErrors
ProxyAddresses
RefreshTokensValidFromDateTime
ShowInAddressList
SignInNames
SipProxyAddress
State
StreetAddress
Surname
TelephoneNumber
UsageLocation
UserPrincipalName
UserState
UserStateChangedOn
UserType
```